# search using two boxes from listview in vb6

Tags: listview, search, vb6, using

I would like to us if it possible to search using two boxes from listview in vb6…

First text box is for company name then the second box is for Number…the idea is that search first in the first textbox(companyname) then the second textbox (number)will search based on the result from first textbox(companyname)…thank you

Comment: what have you made so far ? can you post the relevant code ? the way to do this would be to run the search routine twice, once with the first box, and then again using the results of the first run with the second box

Comment: the search items will come from the listview ? what is the data you are searching in ? are you searching in a string variable, or a textfile, or a database, or another control, or ... ?